# flyway version mistmatch after restore backup from another PC

Tags: postgresql, checksum, flyway

I made database backup from our QA environment and restored it locally.
Then I try to start application locally.

It leads to error that describes that version mistmatch.

Looks like checksum calculates differently for different environments.

Is it expected behaviour?

Comment: Is it possible that your QA environment was updated outside of flyway and/or your flyway versioning scripts have changes/ updates that are not in the QA environment. In these scenarios we have observed such issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, there must be something else going on. Flyway even ignores line endings to deal with these kinds of situations gracefully.

Comment: But it really happens.  My 2 colleagues experienced the same behsviour